# Help with Rachmaninoff's Moments Musicaux no. 4?

Tags: piano

Since first starting to learn the piece, I've been having trouble with the end of the first run on the left hand, specifically the first 3 notes of the last 6 notes (C# C B C Bb B). For those notes, I use the following fingering: 2 - 3 - 4 - 1 - 3 - 2.

The trouble I'm having is with the 2 - 4 - 3 bit, where my 4th finger feels really week when I play it fast, and I have to focus a lot to make the note noticeable.

So my question is: are there any "tricks", drills or techniques that I can use to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like using your 4th finger, don't use it!

Finger it like what it is - a chromatic scale. So the last two groups would be

```
    E | D | C# | E | C# | C | C# | C | B | C | A# | B   
    1   2   3    1   3    1   3    1   2   1   3    2
or  1   2   3    1   2    1   2    1   2   1   3    2
```

You will probably find 3 on all the C#s feels better than 2 - if you have practised your scales enough!

Personally I would probably use 1 on the final B, not 2 - but the *first* thing I do with *all* fingering instructions that were written by an editor, and not the composer him/herself, is ignore them! I find it's much 1 - 3 to play "powerful" passages like this (presto and ff) with 1 and 3 rather than 1 and 2.

EDIT: for some stupid reason, the forum sometimes converts my "unformatted block text" into guitar fingering diagrams! In case it keeps converting, here's the fingering as an image...

[image]

Comment: sorry just tried to fix the nasty guitar diagrams in the `piano answer` just made it worse... => <REJECT> :-/